# Controlling parenthesis while working with operators

Tags: prolog

When working with user-defined operators, Prolog sometimes adds / removes parenthesis to expressions involving those operators automatically.  Is there a way to control this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The parens are just added by portray. They're not part of the internal representation
of the code.  You can override portray to change how things are printed.  see portray_text

Answer (score 1):

An operator is defined like so:

```
:- op(Precedence, Associativity, Operator).
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340873/812818) to a similar question explains this, but the short answer is that the `Associativity` option controls this; `xfy` makes an operator left-associative and `yfx` makes an operator right associative. The `Precedence` tells Prolog how to decide which operator is the subexpression when it sees more than one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What I am not clear about, is if I can remove some extra paranthesis added by Prolog to my expressions, or is this the default??

Comment: I don't think so. Is it a problem or just aesthetically displeasing?

Comment: it is aesthetically displeasing, and I was wondering if there is a way to override that.