# Prolog resolution prover deletes brackets

Tags: syntax, prolog, logic

I'm writing a resolution prover in prolog, which takes inputs of the form

```
[[(a or b) equiv neg(c and d)]]
```

etc., and converts them into CNF. All logical operators work fine, but when the program attempts to expand an `equiv` operation, brackets go missing. For example, performing one step of the algorithm on

```
[[(a and b) equiv c]]
```

gives the result

```
[[neg(a and b) or c], [neg c or a and b]]
```

In the second clause, the brackets around `a and b` have been deleted, while they remain in the first clause. Why is this happening?

For reference, [this](https://pastebin.com/AsPyAHGz) is my code and the command giving that output is `singlestep([[(a and b) equiv c]], X).` The specific code for how `equiv` should be dealt with is at line 93, and the function `singlestep` is at line 108.

Comment: That probably is because of the precedence you defined in your operators, since then these brackets are redundant.

Comment: All operators have the same precedence, except `neg` which is higher. So surely brackets are required when operators are of the same precedence?

Comment: Well, the right one is then left-to-right so `(((neg c) or a) and b)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I think your comment is slightly technically incorrect. When I query `F=(neg c or a and b), F =.. G`, I obtain as a result `G = [or, neg c, a and b]`. Consequently, the expression with parenthesis is `(neg c) or (a and b)`. Consequently, the code by Nathan seems to be correct. In general, if you use Prolog operators, the Prolog system will care about the parenthesis.

Comment: @tphilipp: arrghh yes, it goes in the opposite direction, sorry, somehow mixed it up. Thanks.

Comment: I like to point out some related questions: [Prolog infix operator definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340792/prolog-infix-operator-definition/9340873#9340873) and [Controlling parenthesis while working with operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175400/controlling-parenthesis-while-working-with-operators)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the operator precedence is defined in such a way that

```
neg c or (a and b)
```

and

```
neg c or a and b
```

are equivalent. You do not include your operator declaration, but they are likely to be both `xfy` with equal priority.

To test the equivalence, you could try simple pattern-matching:

```
?- neg c or a and b = X or Y.
X = neg c,
Y = a and b?

?- neg c or a and b = X and Y.
no.
```

Confirming how operators are interpretated.